# How to install MSys2 without user interaction?

Tags: installation, msys

I try to install Msys without asking user any questions:

```
.\msys2.exe --accept-licenses --accept-messages --confirm-command -t c:\msys2
```

But the above command shows a dialog as soon as it starts. How to make it run without user interaction?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try their github.

Answer (score 1):

```
msys.exe install --root C:\MSYS2 --confirm-command
```